# Updating JSP after filtering

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets

Please help me to understand what should I do if I want to update my jsp page after using filter.

For example, my jsp page /index.jsp contains `<div id="login-id">` that I would like to update.
I have a filter that looks like:

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AccessFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/index.jsp</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

public class AccessFilter implements Filter {

private LoginChecker loginChecker;

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

//some code goes here where I get name and hash from the cookies

    loginChecker = new LoginChecker();
    if (loginChecker.isLoggedIn(name, hash)) {
        // here I want to send something into my div
    } else {

    }

    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

I guess that I need to do something like this:

```
HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) response;
resp.getWriter().write("12345");
chain.doFilter(request, resp);
```

And add to index like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.get('index.jsp', function(data) {
        console.log("data = "  + data);
    });
</script>
```

But I think I am wrong because I get whole page instead of just "12345".

Thank you.

Comment: You need to provide some way for your code to know whether you are asking for the full page or just a fragment. For example, you could do a different mapping and jsp to provide the fragment.

Comment: I think that I need a fragment. Because if my filter (loginChecker.isLoggedIn(name, hash) says 'false' then div should stay empty. But if it says 'true' I would like to fill that div with information like 'Logged in as + name (from the cookies)'.

Comment: I think I got it. Made one more empty jsp (loginFragment.jsp) + include as a <jsp:include page="/loginFragment.jsp" /> And a filter for it with a dispatcher INCLUDE, REQUEST. I hope I did right. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

in your case I believe what you are trying to achieve is actually just retrieving values you generated in your Filter in the JSP documents. If this is correct you can go a route like this.

The class HttpServletRequest features the getter/setter setAttributes and getAttributes which you can use very similarly to what you are used to from POST and GET parameters.

In you filter you are then able to set arbitrary data to the attributes map like this.

```
request.setAttribute("data", "my data");
```

If this data is later needed in your JSP you can do something like this:

First make sure that EL Expressions are evaluated in your JSP page by setting the following in the page header:

```
<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>
```

Then you can access the request attributes like this:

```
<p>Hello world this is my JSP and we received ${data} from our filter</p>
```

To clarify the request attributes. Opposed to session attributes the request attributes only live for the time of a single request. This means an usually empty map is created at the beginning of each HTTP request and then gradually gets filled with additional information during the processing run of the request.